# Concatenation/Stitching of Web Image Resources to Improve Load Times

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

So, it's common practice, these days, to concatenate & minify our web app assets like `css` & `javascript`. Almost every technology stack, offers tools to do so.

What I'm wondering, is if there's a way to concatenate all my image resources. That would, I'm sure, load my image heavy site much faster.

I am aware of how this can be manually achieved (think stitching images in PS). I am also aware of algorithms that can automatically do that.

My questions are:

1. Has this become standard practice yet?
2. Are there tools already doing this?
3. Would it really help speed up the loading of the website (by the same logic, I think, it definitely should.

Comment: Google for CSS Sprites. It is common to place all your images/icons in a single file then use css to display the required image. The only drawback is that the images are all background images.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes it is. This is actually a quite old practice dating back far before the web became popular.  Web programmers have been doing this for years.
2. Yes there are;  ex. http://spritegen.website-performance.org/
3. Yes it will, because there aren't as many requests for data the web browser needs to make.  Sure the data load is the same, but the number of requests and responses is lessened.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this this is what works best for me.
CSS. 
Name this styles.css

```
    *, html { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

    body, form, ul, li, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body { background-color: #606061; color: #ffffff; }
    img { border: none; }
    p
   {
        font-size: 1em;
        margin: 0 0 1em 0;
   }

    /* CSS image preload styles */
    body:after
    {
        content: url(img/img01.png) url(img/img02.png) url(img/img03.png) url(img/img04.png) url(img/img05.png)
    }
```

Then in the HTML `<head>` add:

```
   <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="screen" />
        <title>Preload Images</title>

   </head>
```

This should load pretty quick.If not make your image files smaller.